# Failure error in JSch while uploading file to a sftp (Private key auth)

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch

I'm trying to upload a file to a sftp server using JSch libs after private key authentication. But put,mkdir etc actions are throwing failure messages. I tried several ways, sure it looks like a problem in JSch, is any one come across this problem?

The same code(mkdir,put) is working perfect for non private key (username/password) authentication. Could you please help me. sftpChannel.ls is also working in private key approach.

My code:

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    Session session = null;
    if (privateKey != null||"".equals(privateKey)) {
        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
    }

    session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostAddress, port);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    if(password!=null||"".equals(password)){
         session.setPassword(password);
    }

    session.connect();
    Channel channel = null;
    if (sftp) {
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    } else {
        channel = session.openChannel("ftp");
    }
    session.setServerAliveInterval(92000);
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

 // sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(new File(path)), remotePath  );
//         final Vector files = sftpChannel.ls(".");
//        for (Object obj : files) {
//            System.out.println("f:"+obj);
//        }
    sftpChannel.exit();
    session.disconnect();
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" 4: Failure
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.mkdir(ChannelSftp.java:1708)
at zz.beans.RemoteExportBean.exportToFTP(RemoteExportBean.java:52)
at zz.beans.RemoteExportBean.main(RemoteExportBean.java:67)
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" 4: Failure
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.checkStatus(ChannelSftp.java:1946)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:566)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:438)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:405)
at zz.beans.RemoteExportBean.exportToFTP(RemoteExportBean.java:52)
at zz.beans.RemoteExportBean.main(RemoteExportBean.java:66)
```

Comment: It got solved. The remote server was not having enough space to create new files in the that user account. I cleaned the server , not everything is working fine.

-raghu

Comment: Could you add your "solution" as an answer (instead of comment), and then accept it, so it will be seen as solved? Thanks!

Comment: user233640: Paŭlo Ebermann is right. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.